# How to make the grid system centered horizontally?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to get the grid system to center but it won't, i was thinking maybe it has something to do with my pictures' border?. here's the screen shot[what it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlYav.png)
[what i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnSd1.png)

HTML:

```
<div class=" container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="optionBorder">
                <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="optionBorder">
                <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="optionBorder">
                <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.optionBorder
{
    border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    line-height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another element before row with some width and make them center

**for example**.:

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="optionBorder">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="74px" width="50px">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="optionBorder">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="74px" width="50px">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="optionBorder">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="74px" width="50px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
    width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/V8xl1Bn3ge)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
 .paraentCont{
width:100%;
max-width:300px;
margin:auto;
    }
</style>    

 <div class=" container">
  <div class="paraentCont">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="optionBorder">
            <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="optionBorder">
            <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="optionBorder">
            <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May be your code will disturb because container have 1170px width

Answer (score 0):

Give to `.row` fixed width such as 700px, and `margin`-left/right `auto`
look at this example http://www.bootply.com/GFDHc6p5tg

Answer (score 0):

Actually here is there right way to go while using Bootsrap

1. Use the predefine class `text-center`
2. Use q Bootstrap helper like `.inline-block{display: inline-block}`

```css
.inline-block{display: inline-block}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class=" container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4 inline-block">
            <div class="optionBorder">
                <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 inline-block">
            <div class="optionBorder">
                <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 inline-block">
            <div class="optionBorder">
                <img src="images/page-1.svg" height="74px" width="50px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```